# Unable to find a specification for any Pods after running pod setup

Tags: ios, cocoapods

For every pod I try to install, I'm getting the 'unable to find a spec'error.

Here is my podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/yannickl/QRCodeReader.swift.git'
source 'https://github.com/aschuch/QRCode.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'QRCode', '0.2'
pod 'QRCodeReader.swift', '~> 4.3.0'
```

After testing a few times with various changes to the Podfile, I have run:

```
sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
pod setup
```

However that didn't solve it. I'm running El Capitan / XCode 7. Anyone else running into a similar problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would replace the source with CocoaPods specs since both the dependencies are added to the master spec repo.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

Also you need to add `use_frameworks!` since one of your pod is written in swift.

Refer this: https://github.com/yannickl/QRCodeReader.swift

So your podfile will look like this

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

pod 'QRCode', '0.2'
pod 'QRCodeReader.swift', '~> 4.3.0'
```